# Show and Hide issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the code:

Javascript:

```
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
```

CSS:

```
.more {
    display: none;
}

a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #b266b2 ;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }

 a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }

a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      color: #b266b2 ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table width="68%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#313131" background="graphics/backgrounds/tablebg1.png" width="50%"> <font size="4" color="#5be5e5">
    <b>
    - 7/17/2014
    </font>

            <br> <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Click here to view the update log.</a>

            <div id="example" class="more">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="4" color="#b266b2">-</font>  <font size="4"> Completely updated to the new layout everything is functional, unless something broke if that happens please tell me.</font>

                <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="4" color="#b266b2">-</font>  <font size="4"> Going to be working on rewording link names and anything else that needs it next.</font>

                <br> <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Click here to get rid of the update log and possibly never see it again.</a>

            </div>
            <br> <font size="4" color="#5be5e5">
    <b>
    - 5/23/2014
    </font>

            <br> <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Click here to view the update log.</a>

            <div id="example" class="more">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="4" color="#b266b2">-</font>  <font size="4"> Fixed everything involving the Navigation Bar, News Bulletin, and Warning Signs. If there is still something wrong with it please contact me.</font>

                <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="4" color="#b266b2">-</font>  <font size="4"> Edited the layout of the website and shortened the category titles.</font>

                <br> <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Click here to get rid of the update log and possibly never see it again.</a>

            </div>
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is when I click the see more link for 5/23/2014 it displays the information for 7/17/2014. I'm trying to get it so when you click on the see more for 5/23/2014 it displays the information the  under 5/23/2014. Instead when that see more is clicked it opens up the information for 7/17/2014 as if I clicked the see more for that date.

I tried to get a jsfiddle to link but the code did not work for some reason I may have set it up wrong.

If I'm not clear enough let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

EDIT: The issue is the same ids, I'm still fairly new at coding and not sure what exactly I would need to do to make them unique? For example, for the 5/23/2014 I could just put a "1" after the ids but which ids would I need to put a 1 after?

Comment: It would be easier to put that logic in CSS selectors and toggle a single class.

Comment: You have multiple objects with the same ID property.. (`example-show`, `example-hide`).  ID's have to be unique within the page, or you'll run into trouble.  Use `class` if you want multiples.

Comment: `id` values must be unique within a document.  Your duplicated `id`s are invalid.

Comment: That's what I thought it was but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it unique as I am still fairly new at coding could anyone show me an example?

Comment: @Mortuux http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5gvcah6/1/

Comment: @Mortuux but you are not using jQuery in the given code... is jQuery library present in your project..

Comment: There is no jQuery involved from what I can see, why?

Comment: just asking... with jQuery it can be as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5gvcah6/3/ - also you have tagged the question using jQuery

Comment: Oh wow, that would've been quicker and sorry didn't even realize.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/staL64rb/3/

Comment: Perhaps think about your HTML structure a bit more.  It looks like you're working with a list of stuff?  And you want to toggle the display of some items based on user functionality?  Try putting your HTML through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) - I found that very handy when learning.  Whenever you open a tag, indent your code.  Whenever you close a tag, outdent your code.  This keeps everything in line and helps you understand where you are and what you're doing.